# Is it possible to have two actions fire on a form?

Tags: php, html, forms, validation, input

I understand you can't have two form elements. Here is my code below:

```
    <form method="post" action="http://enews.thewebsite.com/q/Z_-p5ayQihZRLi2J67qUQ1aYrMDxK9jLRT" accept-charset="UTF-8">
        <form action="<?php echo $this->getFormActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="newsletter-validate-detail<?php echo $this->getAdditionalFormId(); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="crvs" value="hj8DUzs3ID-3PTnoCEYQBZnP-ywiXCvSIopgDNLjkjI8uXaXEdhIDPteMAiIyBcEx_IEuTzvEtyZyY_6wp6uKKp5ljddRi7lbgSnjg9EM_tdAFCK1mCGHA7rrAZ8_zyk1GjuYtSzOIe60HJ-s5oV9doy1naJOZ-afDbkKAOxuVw"/>
    <div class="form-subscribe">
        <div class="form-subscribe-header">
            <label for="newsletter"><?php echo $this->__('Sign Up to Receive Our Newsletters') ?></label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-subscribe-input"><input name="email" type="text" id="newsletter" value="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" onclick="this.value=='<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>'?this.value='':''" onblur="this.value==''?this.value='<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>':''" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" /></div>
        <div class="form-subscribe-submit"><button type="submit" class="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Sign Up') ?>"><span><?php echo $this->__('Sign Up') ?></span></button></div>
    </div>
</form></form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var newsletterSubscriberFormDetail =  new VarienForm('newsletter-validate-detail<?php echo $this->getAdditionalFormId(); ?>');
    //]]>
</script>
```

The first post action is the one that is taking precedence. I would like them both to fire in the order they are now.

Is this possible?

Perhaps i can use some javascript like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doPreview()
    {
        form=document.getElementById('newsletter-validate-detail');
        form.target='_blank';
        form.action='thewebsite'; //first action
        form.submit();
        form.action='backto-other-action';  //second action???
        form.target='';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: When a form submits, it redirects to the page specified by `action`. Which page do you want to redirect to? You probably want to use AJAX, or in your PHP, redirect one of the pages to the other page.

Comment: It needs to hit that first page which is the enews.thewebsite... and then after that i just want it to go back to the homepage..... which would be the second action URL.  Can i use some javascript maybe to do this?

Comment: Also, note... i don't have access to the first page... it's from a third party website. @4castle

Comment: You can use cURL to send an HTTP request and get an HTTP response from the third party site. Set the form to your own script, then have the script do the request, handle the response, then direct the user as you wish.

Comment: @DissidentRage, that sounds complicated but i like your idea.

Comment: Yes, it's complicated, but it's totally worth learning. You will probably be doing a lot of it in the future.

Comment: Could you link me to an example? I'd love to give it a try and learn this technique. @DissidentRage

Comment: I rather like [this example](/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code#answer-32112981).